# Spring 4.2.6 NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

I am struggling to find the reason for this error to occur.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.my.package.web.repository.ContactFormRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5253)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5543)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1978)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As stated in the headline I use Spring 4.2.6 on a Tomcat 7 with Java 1.7.

Here is some more code with things I already tried  to solve it.

This is the ContactFormRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ContactFormRepository extends JpaRepository<FooterContactForm, Long> {
   List<FooterContactForm> findByCountryName(String countryName);
}
```

I tried to use `CrudRepository` in exchange for `JpaRepository` (I will probably only need Crud). 
I removed `@Repository` and I changed `@Repository` to `@Component`. Both didn't work.

The Repository is used in this Class:

```
@Service
public class SaveDataService {
public static final Class<?> LOGGER = SaveDataService.class;

  @Autowired
  private ContactFormRepository contactFormRepository;

  @Autowired
  private MailService mailService;

  public void saveDataContact(FooterContactForm form, String content){
      contactFormRepository.save(form);
  }

}
```

In my app-config.xml I have the following lines, which I thought should be sufficient.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="de.my.package.web"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="de.my.package.web.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/mail.properties"/>
</bean>

<!-- SET default mail properties -->
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.smtpHost:localhost}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${mail.smtpPort:25}"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <!-- check property file(s) every 5 minutes -->
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="300"/>
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/contactFooter"/>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!-- thymeleaf -->

<bean id="emailTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="templates/"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>


<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="emailTemplateResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/FrontendApps"/>
</bean>
<bean id="emf"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.my.package.web" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>

</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

The package names are correct. 
Any hints what might cause this error?

Edit: 
The app-config.xml file gets loaded within the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/readRssFeed</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>createToken</filter-name>
    <filter-class>de.my.package.web.filter.CreateCsrfTokenFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>validateToken</filter-name>
    <filter-class>de.my.package.web.filter.ValidateCsrfTokenFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>protectSpam</filter-name>
    <filter-class>de.my.package.web.filter.SpamProtectionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>createToken</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>validateToken</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>protectSpam</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <description>FrontendApps DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/FrontendApps</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Edit 2: added the full web.xml and full app-config.xml

Comment: Are you reading `config.xml`?

Comment: Yes I do. Its the typical application-context file.

Comment: How are you loading things (web.xml or java) please add that to your question.

Comment: Please add the full web.xml... Not a snippet. Also if that is really what you have it should work, so I doubt that what you posted is what your actual configuration looks like.

Comment: Could you please post the full app-config.xml?

Comment: I added both of the files. And yes this really is what I have.

Comment: sometimes I have issues with dependencies between beans in that beans manage to load before the repositories have been scanned etc... try adding some dependencies between beans.

Comment: You're context is ok, you've got everything there.  I think you should remove the @Repository annotation on your interface, you've already told to spring where to scan classes extending Spring Data Repository interfaces when you declared `<jpa:repositories base-package="de.my.package.web.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>`.

Comment: @RaeBurawes I removed the annotation. But unfortunatley this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but this declaration inside your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

tells that it's only confine to the DispatcherServlet.  Can try to create another `applicationContext.xml` file in your project e.g. `/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml`, move the model, repository, and service layer related beans there. Then add the following to your `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I was trying to post this as a comment, but the characters are limited.

Comment: I created a new applicationContext.xml and declared all beans neccessary in this file. Then added the <context-param> as you suggested, but the error persists. Could it also be the tomcat caching some files? I cannot continue to work on this issue until next monday unfortunatley.

Comment: Hmmmm.. are the xml context files being included in the package when you build it?